# word file preview on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, ms-word

is there any way to show a preview content of word file?? like sample application feed viewer? if so please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is:

1. Convert MS Word file to images. I.e. print first couple of pages to image. This can be done on command line with Open Office or by installing a printer driver that prints to images.
2. Use these images for preview

Since this takes too much time to be done on-demand, you will have to batch-process all existing documents and schedule processing for new documents as these are added to the system.

Comment: i need to know are there any introp service to do that image generation will be too slow the proces

Comment: No. Word 2007 onward do have "preview" feature but it is not exposed via API. Batch creation of preview images is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way, you can [convert](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/convertdocintootherformat.aspx) Word file to HTML and than display it on your ASP.NET page.

Comment: no this way is not what i'm expecting this is only doc conversion.

Comment: It is just example, I was using this for all Word types and it works.